# Getting extra letters after scanning the barcode using Java

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner, scanning

I have created an application which generates the barcode.

Here is the code how I created the barcode:

```
Code39 code39 = new Code39();
String outputStr = code39.encode("B00009", 1);
//String humanTextStr=code39.getHumanText();
lblBarcode.setText(outputStr);
lblBarcode.setFont(new java.awt.Font("CCode39_S3_Trial",java.awt.Font.PLAIN,14));
```

Using this java library **ConnectCodeBarcodeFontLibrary.jar**.

For scanning the barcode I used [QRbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.qrbot&hl=en) app which gives me this information - extra letter at the end `B00009K` instead of this `B00009`.

Here is the screenshot of generated barcode:

[image]

What is the problem in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the [@kunif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825242/getting-extra-letters-after-scanning-the-barcode-using-java/62857390#62857390)'s answer of `ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT` code which saying that it uses a check digit. So, I have analyzed my code and I found that `code39.encode("B00009", 1);` passing the second parameter 1 which is the reason why it generates the extra letter `K` at the end of barcode number.

So, I changed the 1 which 0 and now its scanning the barcode correctly.

```
String outputStr = code39.encode("B00009", 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Code 39 has the option of using a check digit and is called Code 39 mod 43.
[Code 39 mod 43 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Code_39_mod_43)

For example, ZXing's Code39Reader has an option called ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT (a mode in which a check digit is generated from barcode data even if there is no check digit and is notified?).
[Class Code39Reader](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/oned/Code39Reader.html)

> ```
> public Result decodeRow(int rowNumber,
>                         BitArray row,
>                         Map<DecodeHintType,?> hints)
>                  throws NotFoundException,
>                         ChecksumException,
>                         FormatException
> ```

[ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html#ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT)

> public static final DecodeHintType ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT
> Assume Code 39 codes employ a check digit. Doesn't matter what it maps to; use Boolean.TRUE.

Whether your program added a check digit when it generated the barcode (but did not print it in human-readable characters), or whether the program that read the barcode supplemented the check digit and generated/notified it. There can be one of two possibilities.

By the way, the last `K` was notified when the barcode presented was read with the Honeywell Xenon 1900 in the default No Check Character mode, so a check digit may have been added when generating the barcode in your program. Will be high.